# Problems with GIT flow finishing features

Tags: git, git-flow

Something strange happend when finishing a feature using GIT flow.

1. I create the feature - `feature start`
2. In `develop` branch something has being commited, so, develop is one commit ahead of the feature.
3. I make the first commit on the feature with all my changes.
4. To finish with my feature, I make a `feature finish` and it says all was OK.

So, at this point, we should see the branch `FEATURE` closed and merged to `develop` BUT I realize that there was one conflict (from that commit ahead at `develop`) that I didn't resolved and the branch was already close. When resolving and commiting the conflict, the commit marked as a merge from `develop` to `develop` when, theoretically, was a merge from `FEATURE` to `develop`.

My questions are:

1. Is this normal?
2. What I must do (apart from `feature start` and `feature finish`) to avoid this behaviour?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 2, I typically always rebase the feature branch against the head of the develop branch, prior to finishing the feature branch.  That way, any merge conflicts are resolved on the feature branch, prior to merging into develop.  It also, in my opinion, helps to keep the history of the repository easier to read and understand.